# PHP find and return neighbor value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like so:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string 'news-article' (length=12)
      'count' => int 139
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string 'industry-resource' (length=17)
      'count' => int 37
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string 'editorial' (length=9)
      'count' => int 33
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string 'bulletin' (length=8)
      'count' => int 12
```

and I'm trying create a function that searches for a `term` and returns it's neighboring value, `count`.

My inclination was to use `array_search()`, however using this returns `false`, I'm guessin because it's only searching the first layer of the array (0,1,2,3).

I'm not so much looking for an exact answer but a nudge in the right direction. I'm guessing it will require looping through the array, but I do not know how to approach getting the neighboring `count` value once the `term` value is located. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop through the array and access them directly.

```
$search_term = "news-article";
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $element) {
    if($element['term'] == $search_term) {
        $count = $element['count'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Charlotte--your eloquent solution makes me realize how much I over-thought it!